# In the derived class the compiler doesn't recognize a variable of parent class unless the variable is in the cinstructor

Tags: c#

I have the following bellow.

The compiler recognizes the variable flyBehaviour in the derived class only
if the variable is in the constructor.
Why is that?

```
abstract class Duck
{
    protected IFlyBehaviour flyBehaviour;

    public IFlyBehaviour FlyBehaviour
    {
        get
        {return flyBehaviour;}
        set
        {flyBehaviour=value;}
    }

}

class MullardDuck: Duck
{
    flyBehaviour  //the compiler doesn't recognize this variable here
    public MullardDuck()
    {
        flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings(); //here the compiler recognize this variable
    }
}
```

Comment: why on Earth would the compiler recognise a variable out of a function, property, or anywhere where you should write that?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a syntax error, not due to inheritance.

You couldn't write this either :

```
abstract class Duck
{
    protected IFlyBehaviour flyBehaviour;
    flyBehaviour = ... ; // This wouldn't compile.

    public IFlyBehaviour FlyBehaviour
    {
        get
        {return flyBehaviour;}
        set
        {flyBehaviour=value;}
    }
}
```

By calling **flyBehaviour**, you call the protected field which is already defined, but in the base class.

If you want to initialize that field, you have to do it in the constructor, as you figured, or you can manipulate the value in any method or property.

```
class MullardDuck: Duck
{
    public MullardDuck()
    {
        // You can access the field from the constructor
        this.flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings();
    }

    public void Method(){
        // You can also access the field from a method
        this.flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to use that var in that place? can't you only do something like this if you say that in this place the var is recognized?

```
class MullardDuck: Duck
{
    IFlyBehaviour mullardFlyBehaviour;
    public MullardDuck(){
        mullardFlyBehaviour = flyBehaviour;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable in a method of derived class. Try to access the variable in the MullarDuck() function (constructor) or any other function you might define in the derived class. As per definition, the derived class already have this variable so you don't have to access that variable outside any method or property.

If you want to assign any value to this variable, you will have to assign it either in a method or in a property.